# Как заполнить шаблон xlsx, используя PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Есть множество различных .xlsx шаблонов.
И есть набор данных, один и тот же для всех шаблонов.
Сейчас все работает через PHPExcel, просто вставляются данные в шаблон. 
Каждая переменная в свою ячейку. Но это очень не удобно. Для каждого из шаблонов приходится писать свой метод.

Можно ли как-то заполнять .xlsx шаблон какими-то метками, а потом заменять их? Это помогло бы избавиться от большого количества кода. У меня бы в каждом файле просто были бы написаны метки вроде {{data.name}}

PHPExcel - большая библиотека, но я еще не нашел в ней такого функционала.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: [именованные ячейки/диапазоны](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU) использовать нельзя что ли?

Comment: а потом `$sheet->getCell('sampleCellName')->setValue(....)`

Comment: Можете отправить меня на страничку с информацией по этому поводу?

Comment: увидел ссылку, спасибо!!!

Comment: для наглядности: http://s3.aws.blueriver.com/it/intuit/assets/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Excel8.png - задание имени ячейки/диапазона. Ну а по использованию в пхп, в  наверное как выше написано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За ответ спасибо [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran)
Нам нужно использовать [именованные ячейки/диапазоны](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU)
А потом в коде с PHPExcel `$sheet->getCell('sampleCellName')->setValue(....)`

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**
У меня была проблема с PHPExcel при именовании ячеек строчными символами, именуйте заглавными и все будет OK!